# Running asp.net app that accesses sharepoint web services on same server - getting 401 Unauthorized

Tags: 401

I have an asp.net appliation that makes use of sharepoint web services that is running on the same server as my sharepoint installation. I was using computername:portnumber to access the site, but assigned a 'friendly' URL on my DNS server for users to use. This 'broke' my asp.net app that accesses web services. I am now getting 401-Unauthorized. Anyone have any ideas as to why this is happening because of a URL change?

Answer (score 1):

Try http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861 this is a common "gotcha" with any fqdn on the same server.